# GGTS no sources attached

Tags: eclipse, grails, dependency-management

I am playing with grails within GGTS IDE. After creating new project, there is plenty of jars included by default but there no sources included. Version of grails is 2.2.4. I've tried refresh-dependencies --include-source or even right click project and basicaly do the same thing but I am still getting only bytecode displayed.

When I add new dependency into BuildConfig.groovy file sources got included by default. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found workaround to get my sources downloaded without gant. First I installed [eclipse link plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/eclipse-scripts#_=_). After that I run [`grails create-pom <package>`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-pom.html) and download sources with m2e plugin. After that I run `grails sts-link-sources-and-javadocs` and `eclipse: File -> Restart`.